# Order of Fragment Lifecycle Methods

Tags: java, android, android-layout

IF i have multiple fragments in my layout, what exactly is the order in which their lifecycle methods are called? Am i right in thinking Fragment 1's onAttach(), onCreate(), onCreateView() is run first followed by the same three methods for Fragment 2? And then each of the fragments onStart() is called in the order in which the fragments are defined in the layout? If anyone can point me to a resource that clearly defines this ordering it would really help!

Comment: you can also make a test and print out callbacks from each fragment.